# Improving recursive `rmdir` in ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, directory, rmdir

I have a lot of directories that are empty, save for other empty directories inside them. They are also mixed with other directories that do have files in them, so I want to only delete the empty directories and their (now empty) parents.

I’ve come up with this:

```
empty_dirs = -> { Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*").select { |d| File.directory?(d) && Dir.empty?(d) } }
empty_dirs.call.each { |d| Dir.rmdir(d) } until empty_dirs.call.empty?
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if there’s a standard way — like `FileUtils.rmdir_r(dir)` — instead of having to write a loop.

Answer (score 3):

`Dir.rmdir` is a wrapper for shell’s `rmdir` which fails when the directory is not empty (ruby version raises an exception)

> Errno::ENOTEMPTY: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir

One might take advantage of this

```
Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*").
  select(&File.method(:directory?)).
  sort_by(&:length).  # to start as deep as possible
  reverse.         # longest first 
  each do |directory|
    Dir.rmdir(directory) rescue :skipped 
  end
```

Comment: That’s a longer version of [my first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50665333/1). Not really better than my current solution. Notice I’ve posted *working code*; I’m looking for something I might not know of (like `FileUtils.rmdir_r(dir)`, or something).

Comment: No, your code is not working. It fails on deeply nested empty dirs.

Comment: Pretty sure my code is working. I’ve just tried it with directories nested fourteen and twenty-two levels deep. Then just for kicks I tried on directories over sixty levels deep. They all worked without a hitch. Your code, on the other hand, is giving me an `ArgumentError` around the `sort(&:length)`.

Comment: Yeah, there should be `sort_by` not `sort`. If you think your code is working, then fine; I’ll leave the correct answer here for the future readers.

Comment: If you think my code isn’t working, then I’d like to know why. All my tests show it working fine, so if you claim it fails in certain situations, I’d like to understand what those are. Yours isn’t “the correct answer”. My question was always about a solution better than what I have (which this isn’t), not any working solution (that I already had two of).

Comment: I do not _think_, I _know_. The two additional lines (`sort_by` and `reverse`) in my solution give a dead-clear hint on the subject. Test it on `dir1/dir2/dir3`, all directories empty, just having a nested subdirectory. I believe the whole `dir1` should be removed, while your solution will delete the leaf `dir3` only. If you are fine with leaving empty directories, just use `Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*").each { |directory| Dir.rmdir(directory) rescue :skipped }` which is a one-liner.

Comment: “Yours isn’t ‘the correct answer’.”—next time add “IMHO” to this kind of sentences.

Comment: I just explained I tested it with *over sixty levels of nested directories and it worked*. You’re the one who should test my code. The reason it works is the `until` keeps the loop running while there are empty directories.

Comment: I don’t need to add “IMHO” because I asked the question and defined what a correct answer is since I am looking to know if a specific solution exists. If an answer does not fill the requested parameters, it isn’t *the* correct answer. It is *an* answer, though, and since it works after your edit, I’ll upvote it.

Comment: @user137369 this answer appears to be far more efficient since yours will regularly check to see if there are more directories in `empty_dirs`. For example add a puts statement into the `empty_dirs` lambda and see how many times this is called.

Comment: @engineersmnky this is not as important as that this answer removes empty dirs recursively, while the code in the question does not. ^w it indeed does as well.

Comment: @mudasobwa importance is a matter of perspective and my perspective when reading "I have alot" is performance should be important.

Comment: “this answer removes empty dirs recursively, while the code in the question does not”. Holy crap, you’re stubborn. Try the code! It does work recursively. How many times do I have to repeat I’ve done it successfully with over sixty levels of nested empty directories? If you refuse to try the code, that’s your prerogative, but it does not make it not work just because you can’t understand it.

Comment: @engineersmnky I do agree performance is an important factor, and that this approach will be more performant most of the time.